# Dropdown navigation menu item disappearing after hover

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu, navigation

I am using bootstrap to build my site and the main navigation uses dropdowns for second level choices.

In IE10 only (works everywhere else), the dropdown menu is inconsistently accessible and if you are able to access the second level choices, they disappear after hovering off of them. In other words as you hover down the list of menu items, the one above will disappear when you hover onto the menu item below it. Perhaps there are two problems: one being you can't access the dropdown (maybe a padding issue?) but the disappearing problem, I have never seen before.

[Here's my fiddle with the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/mf37V/3/)

(**When viewing the fiddle make sure to adjust the width of the Result panel otherwise it will be collapsed for mobile)

My html is pretty simple:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">

<div class="navbar-collapse collapse"><!--NAVIGATION-->    

<ul class='nav navbar-nav'>
<li class='first'><a href="#">Getting Around</a>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" tabindex="17">Find Your Ride</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" tabindex="18">Transit Overview</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" tabindex="19">Carpool/Vanpool</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" tabindex="20">Biking &amp; Walking</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Travel Training</a>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Do It Yourself</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Transit Orientation</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Transit Ambassadors</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Schedule a Training</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#" tabindex="26">Senior Safe Driving</a></li>
<li><a href="#" tabindex="27">Programs &amp; Services</a>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" tabindex="28">Mobility Programs &amp; Services Locator</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" tabindex="29">Mobility Programs Overview</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>


</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance! I am stumped.

Comment: Are you trying to make this mobile friendly?...

Comment: Yes, I am using bootstrap's default mobile menu. I didn't include that in the html above or in the fiddle.  Under 768px, the menu is collapsed and accessed by a list menu icon. I don't think that is affecting this though.

Comment: Then you should not be trying to go for a hover effect... how will you over on a mobile device?.

Comment: There is different css for the menu under 768 pixels that doesn't involve the dropdown menus.

Comment: Do you have the following tag in your header section? <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A variety of issues at work here, but I seem to have solved it. IE10 doesn't play well with display:none and once I replaced with visability: hidden on my navbar>li>ul, things seemed much better.

Also, can't confirm but since bootstrap adds a background color of transparent to its a tags, I think the background color of the list items we're going transparent. Adding a background color, adjusting the line-height seem to fix.

link to fiddle in original now works correctly in IE10.